# Is "less than" for rational numbers decideable in Coq?

Tags: comparison, coq, rational-number, decidable

In the Coq standard library, the "less than" relation is decidable for the natural numbers (`lt_dec`) and for the  integers (`Z_lt_dec`). When I search however (`Search ({ _ _ _ } + {~ _ _ _ })`) I can't find a `Q_le_dec` or `Qle_dec` for the rationals, only `Qeq_dec` for decidable equality.

Is this because the "less than" relation is not decideable for the rationals in Coq? Or is it decideable but the decision procedure is just not implemented in the standard library?

Comment: Rationals in Coq are represented in the obvious way, as pairs of a numerator and a positive denominator (in other words, `Print Q` shows `Record Q : Set := Qmake { Qnum : Z;  Qden : positive }`). So, to answer your first question, comparison of rationals is decidable, and the decision procedure is easy to implement: `a/b < c/d` iff `a×d < b×c`.

Answer (score 5):

A quick look at Coq's standard library gives two lemmas, albeit not in the exact form you have searched for:

- [Q_dec](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.QArith.QArith_base.html#Q_dec) about the decidability of comparison (`{x < y } + { x > y } + { x = y }`);
- [Q_lt_le_dec](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.QArith.QArith_base.html#Qlt_le_dec) (`{ x<y } + { y<=x }`).

I admit I haven't made the exercise, but it seems like you can easily derive whatever decidability result over `Qle` or `Qlt` you want from there.